# What's the difference between the `USER` and `USERNAME` environment variables?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I'm not entirely sure which one to use.

Comment: It's actually not Ruby specific. These are environment variables that any type of script or executable can see and use.

Comment: I'm more concerned about OS-compatibility. Will `ENV['USER']` exist on Mac installs? Does `ENV['USER'] == ENV['USERNAME']` on Linux installs? Etc..

Comment: On Linux, would you have `LOGNAME`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- **On windows:** `ENV['username']` will output the current username.
- **On linux:** If the script is run through `sudo`, `"USER"` will be the `sudo`-ed-to user (usually `root`) and "USERNAME" will be the user who ran sudo.
- **On Mac :** only USER exists (on MacOS 10.15. To be confirmed on previous versions)

Here's a list of XP Environment variables: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm

And here's a list of Vista/7 Environment variables, you'll notice they are slightly different: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment-variables-windows-vista-7.htm

Edit:
The safest approach would be to write a small function that determines what system you are on (I gather from your comment above you're wanting a Write-Once, Run-Anywhere app) and sets the appropriate values based upon that.

Comment: I have a Bash script `echo $USERNAME`. When I run it with `sudo ./name.sh` it always prints `root`. So I'm not sure about the statement `"USERNAME" will be the user who ran sudo`. Do you have a source for that? As far as I can tell, `$USER` and `$USERNAME` are identical, though in some environments `$USERNAME` does not exist.

Comment: If you run `sudo bash` and then within that shell run `printenv` you'll get `USER=root` `SUDO_USER=<original user's name>` `USERNAME=root`. This is on Ubuntu 16.04.4.

Answer (score 2):

if it is Ruby 1.8.6 or 1.9.2, there is only `ENV['USER']` (on Mac):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > ENV.keys.grep /user/i
 => ["USER", "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"]
```

Comment: See, I'm on Ruby 1.9.2 on Win 7 and I have both `ENV["USER"]` and `ENV["USERNAME"]`